# Как лучше реализовать данную задачу с генератором случайных чисел?

Tags: java, api

[image: Пример с книги]
[image: Пример от меня №1]
[image: Пример от меня №2]

На картинках выше представлены три способа реализации генератора случайных чисел от 11 до 99.

На рис. №1, реализация, которая была представлена в книге. Я не считаю, что данный способ является лучшей, так как приходится всё время, при вызове функции, создать новый экземпляр объекта Random — это негативно влияет на производительность.
На рис. №2 и №3 отображены мои способы решения данной проблемы.

Какая из этого всего является наилучшим способом реализации данной задачи?
Предложите, пожалуйста, свой вариант, который считаете лучшей. Мне важно узнать, как в таких случаях поступают.

Comment: вместо скрина кода, добавьте его текст в вопрос (форматирование кода тут есть)

Comment: У меня не сохранился код. Скрины старые.

Comment: если есть желание получить ответ, то лучше перепечать/распознать текст и вставить его в ответ (с текстом будет больше вероятность его получить)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class RandomGeneratorServiceImpl implements RandomGeneratorService {
    private static final Random r = new Random();

    private static final int MINIMUM_FACTOR = 11;
    private static final int MAXIMUM_FACTOR = 99;

    @Override
    public int generateRandomFactor() {
        return r.nextInt((MAXIMUM_FACTOR - MINIMUM_FACTOR + 1) - MINIMUM_FACTOR);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы повторили опечатку за автором вопроса. И добавили свою.